# Is there a way to merge my current working branch into master, without switching to master first?

Tags: git

Say I'm on `feature-branch`, is there a way to do `git merge <this-branch> into master`, then do `git checkout master` and have my new features be there waiting for me?

What I want to avoid is "turning back time" from my current branch, by switching back to master before doing the merge. I just want master to catch up to where I'm at in my current branch, without losing my place.

Comment: I have seen answers going around `git merge-tree`which _could_ create a tree object with what the merge would look like if you attempted to run it and it will print the tree id, then with that tree id you can run `git commit-tree` which you can use to create a commit where you can set the branches in the order you want and then you can move a branch to that commit.

Comment: When I said _" where you can set the branches in the order you want"_, I am referring to _parents_ of the commit. You can set them in the order you desired (which is a topic in itself outside of the scope of the question).

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot do a *true merge* into a branch without having that branch checked out into the working tree. Git needs a place to enact the merge.

You can, however, do a fast forward into a branch without checking it out. Thus, for instance, you do not have to check out master in order to fetch / pull to it from the remote. In fact, as I have explained elsewhere, if you are using pull requests on the remote, you don't need a local master at all.

And in the same way I would argue there is no merit to merging into master intermittently while working your feature. A better option, if the problem is that your branch is taking a long time to write, is to keep merging origin/main (after fetch) into your branch.

Comment: I have come to learn about `git merge-tree` and then having a tree you can create a commit with `git commit-tree` and then you can move a branch to that commit.... Let me see if I can answer that question fast... it makes this question a duplicate.